# is it possible to use pixel coordinate to add a marker on a map

Tags: flutter, dart, pixel

I am using an openstreet map plugin and for now there is no method to add Marker click listeners on a map, hence i want to add it from the flutter side . The only way i can do it using it with a stack widget and find the coordinates of the map, then convert those coordinates to PixelCoordinates and use that info on the position widget attributes, left and top.

Here in the initState i have converted the click cooridnates to normal pixel coordinates

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    osmController = MapController(
      initMapWithUserPosition: true,
    );
    osmController!.addObserver(this);
    osmController!.listenerMapSingleTapping.addListener(() async {
      GeoPoint? p = osmController!.listenerMapSingleTapping.value;
      print(p);

      LatLng latLng = LatLng(p!.latitude, p.longitude);
      
      num worldWidth = 256 * pow(2, 18);
      print('map worldwidth $worldWidth');
      double pixelX = (latLng.longitude + 180) / 360 * worldWidth;
      double sinLatitude = sin(latLng.latitude * pi / 180);
      double pixelY =
          (0.5 - log((1 + sinLatitude) / (1 - sinLatitude)) / (4 * pi)) *
              worldWidth;

      print('Pixel point: Point($pixelX, $pixelY)');
    });
  }
```

The result i get is `Pixel point: (49464318.85714286, 28176661.14285714)`

Now, i want to use this value in my positioned widget to show an icon like this

```
class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> with OSMMixinObserver {
  late MapController? osmController;
  late Point<double> pixelLocation = Point(0, 0);
  final GlobalKey _mapKey = GlobalKey();
  late Position position;
  late GeoPoint? initPos;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        osmFlutter(mapKey: _mapKey, osmController: osmController),
        Positioned(
          left: 49464318.85714286,
          top: 28176661.14285714,
          //child: Transform.translate(
          //offset: Offset(pixelLocation.x, pixelLocation.y),
          child: Icon(
            Icons.location_on,
            size: 24,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          //  ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 10.0,
          left: 10.0,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: _addMarker,
            child: Text('Add Marker'),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

I am not sure if this approach will even work, just wanted opinions, the value    `left: 49464318.85714286,top: 28176661.14285714,` seems way too off, but the pixel coordinates are correct. Any tips ?

Comment: check https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_osm_interface/0.1.31/flutter_osm_interface/MarkerIcon-class.html - this is where you can create a marker - all you need is to pass any widget that listens to tap events

Comment: Nope, not implemented yet where a marker listens to a tap event.

Comment: what is not implemented? [addMarker](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_osm_plugin/latest/osm_flutter/MapController/addMarker.html) method?

Comment: The addMarker is implemented but the when a I click on it, nothing happens meaning, the onclick method on marker is not implemented as the marker is passed on to the native code side, there isn't much I can do on the flutter side. Gesturedetector wont work ..